# How to convert MCMC diagnostics to Latex table?

Tags: r, latex, mcmc

I'm using the `coda` package to calculate the summary statistics of my MCMC. However, there seems to be no options to convert the printed summary into a Latex table. I've tried `stargazer`, and coercing `summary.mcmc` results to a data frame. Both attempts have failed.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(coda)
mock_mcmc <- mcmc(rnorm(1000))
summary(mock_mcmc)
```

`summary.mcmc` will print out

```
1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

          Mean             SD       Naive SE Time-series SE 
       0.03180        0.98715        0.03122        0.03368 

2. Quantiles for each variable:

    2.5%      25%      50%      75%    97.5% 
-1.89794 -0.65289  0.02952  0.67396  1.97158
```

How do I output that result table into a Latex file? I understand that it is possible to calculate the summary statistics by hand, but I'm curious whether there's a convenient feature of coda that I don't know about.

Comment: What exactly do you want in this table? You should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. Also be more explicit about how attempts have failed.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do it in coda. The method below defines a method of xtable for mcmc objects by converting the object to a dataframe and then rerunning xtable.

```
library(coda)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(xtable)

xtable.summary.mcmc = function(x, ...)
  x %>%
  use_series(statistics) %>%
  c(x %>%
      use_series(quantiles) ) %>%
  as.list %>%
  dplyr::as_data_frame() %>%
  xtable(...)

1000 %>% 
  rnorm %>% 
  mcmc %>% 
  summary %>%
  xtable
```

Comment: can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: What's doing on in the last few lines is `xtable(summary(mcmc(rnorm(1000))))`

Answer (score 0):

The key is to extract the relevant quantities from the output. To find the appropriate quantities, use the `names()` function in R.

```
library(coda)
library(xtable)

mock_mcmc = mcmc(rnorm(1000))
s = summary(mock_mcmc)

stats_table = xtable(as.data.frame(t(s$statistics)))
quant_table = xtable(as.data.frame(t(s$quantiles)))

print(stats_table, file="stats_table.tex")
print(quant_table, file="quant_table.tex")
```